# Flutter como llamar a otras paginas dedes el bottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter

He creado una pantalla donde tengo 5 widgets ya creados y que funcionan corrctamente , ahora e añadido una  bottomNavigationBar que se posiciona y funciona y se ve visualmente correctamente , el problema es que nose como enlazarle a los botones que ya tine las otras paginas que tengo creadas , e probado mucas cosas pero con mi codigo alctual nose como hacerlo. Solo me falta hacerle las llamadas a las otras paginas .
Un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int _selectedIndex = 0;
    class MyAppState extends State<Myappdos> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp( 
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold( 
          bottomNavigationBar:
           BottomNavigationBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              selectedFontSize: 17.4,
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
              onTap: (int index){
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndex = index;
                });
              },
              fixedColor: Colors.blue,//cuando clikamos el color k se vera
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              items: < BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_home.png', width: 26),
                  activeIcon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_home_active.png', width: 26),
                  title: Text('Inicio')
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_search.png', width: 26),
                  activeIcon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_search_active.png', width: 26),
                  title: Text('Buscar')
                ),
                 BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_camera.png', width: 26),
                  activeIcon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_camera_active.png', width: 26),
                  title: Text('Publicar')
                ),
                 BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_notifications.png', width: 26),
                  activeIcon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_notifications_active.png', width: 26),
                  title: Text('Notificaciones')
                ),
                 BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_user.png', width: 26),
                  activeIcon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_user_active.png', width: 26),
                  title: Text('Perfil',)
              ),
            ]
          ),
            body:Container(
          child:Column( 
            children:<Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: 5,
                ),
                child: renderAppBar(),
              ),
              renderPata(),
              renderFoto(),
              renderIconos(),
              renderTexto(),
            ]
          ),
          ),
        )
        );
      }
}
```

Comment: Podrías compartir algo mas que indique lo que necesitas mas específicamente por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto se puede realizar de diferentes maneras, una manera fácil seria la siguiente

### 1. Creamos el home

Para este caso seria la primera pantalla a mostrar en tu app, que supongo es lo que tienes en estos momentos en el código.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: 5,
          ),
          child: renderAppBar(),
        ),
        renderPata(),
        renderFoto(),
        renderIconos(),
        renderTexto(),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

### 2. Creamos una segunda página para cuestiones de ejemplo.

```
class PaginaDos extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child:Text('Pagina dos')
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### 3. Con lo que ya tiene se hace referencia a las 2 páginas

```
final _pages = [Home(),PaginaDos()];
```

Esto se lo asignamos al `body` del `Scaffold` que es el que contiene nuestro `BottomNavigationBar`

```
body: _pages[_selectedIndex],
```

### Código Final

```
class MyAppState extends State<Myappdos> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final _pages = [Home(),PaginaDos()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              selectedFontSize: 17.4,
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
              onTap: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndex = index;
                });
              },
              fixedColor: Colors.blue, //cuando clikamos el color k se vera
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_home.png',
                        width: 26),
                    activeIcon: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/icons/ic_home_active.png',
                        width: 26),
                    title: Text('Inicio')),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_search.png',
                        width: 26),
                    activeIcon: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/icons/ic_search_active.png',
                        width: 26),
                    title: Text('Buscar')),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_camera.png',
                        width: 26),
                    activeIcon: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/icons/ic_camera_active.png',
                        width: 26),
                    title: Text('Publicar')),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/icons/ic_notifications.png',
                        width: 26),
                    activeIcon: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/icons/ic_notifications_active.png',
                        width: 26),
                    title: Text('Notificaciones')),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_user.png',
                        width: 26),
                    activeIcon: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/icons/ic_user_active.png',
                        width: 26),
                    title: Text(
                      'Perfil',
                    )),
              ]),
          body:  _pages[_selectedIndex],
        ));
  }
}
```

---

## Navegación mediante rutas

Lo siguiente es a modo de ejemplo para navegar de una pagina a otra.

### Definé las rutas

```
MaterialApp(
  // Inicie la aplicación con la ruta con nombre "/". En nuestro caso, la aplicación comenzará
  // en el Widget FirstScreen
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    // Cuando naveguemos hacia la ruta "/", crearemos el Widget FirstScreen
    '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
    // Cuando naveguemos hacia la ruta "/second", crearemos el Widget SecondScreen
    '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
  },
);
```

### Navega a la segunda pantalla

```
// Dentro del Widget `FirstScreen` con el uso de un button
onPressed: () {
  // Navega a la segunda pantalla usando una ruta con nombre
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
}
```

### Regresa a la primera pantalla

```
// Dentro del widget SecondScreen
onPressed: () {
  // Navega de regreso a la primera pantalla haciendo clic en la ruta actual
  // fuera de la pila
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

Puedes encontrar mas información sobre las rutas con nombre en la [pagina oficial](https://flutter-es.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes).

Comment: Hola richard , tengo otra pagina que es la que se muestra namas arrancar la app que es un login , claro la question es que donde pones el codigo de creamos la home no es la home sino que es la 2 pantalla de la app la que debe de tener los dos condigos juntos , hay la question como implementar los 5 widgest mas la botomnavigation bary desde ya la 2 pantalla llamar a otras .

Comment: añadi una imagen.

Comment: @joelcollado cuando me refiero a **Home** no es la primera página de tu app si no la primera página que se muestra al llegar a a la pagina del `BottomNavigationBar`, podrías especificar un poco mas cual es el problema en tu pregunta por favor. La imagen solo me da a entender que Perfil es un contenido mas de tu menu

Comment: nono eso esta bien richar mi problema es que no puedo fusionar en una misma pagina el codigo de los widgets y el codigo de la botonnavigationbar , osea o instancio la botonnavigationbar como tu me as dicho o instancio los widgets pero no encuentro un codigo donde los dos esten en la misma pagina .ose que se vea como en la foto porque el problmea surge cuando tengo k meterle esto _pages[_selectedIndex]  al body que no puedo porque esta ocupado ya.

Comment: @joelcollado, Si entiendo bien tu tienes todos los `Widgets` en un solo archivo? que es tu archivo **main.dart** que es también donde esta el `BottomNavigationBar`?. si es correcto lo que digo, coloca lo puse en el **paso 1** en otro archivo .dart tal cual esta y lo mandas a llamar como te puse el ejemplo

Comment: Hola richard ya pude solucionarlo como decias muchas gracias . Un saludo.